# Python Looping with input parameters

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, input

I am new to programming and I  am trying to write a python script where the user is asked if they would like to add a name and student to the student list. If they say yes, then they are asked for the input of the name and the id. However, if they say no, its suppose to print whatever is already stored in the student list.

This is my code:

```
students = [ ]

def prompt_add():

add_more_student = bool(input("Do you want to add students to this list? (yes/NO):"))

add_student(())

if bool == 'yes':
        add_student(())
else:

    print(students)

def add_student(name, student_id=133):

    student_name = input("Enter a name:")
    student_id = input("Enter number:")

    student = {"name": name, "student_id": student_id}
    students.append(student)
    prompt_add()
    return students

prompt_add()
```

This is the output it keeps printing:

[image: screenshot]

Turns out that regardless of if I type yes or no, I still get the question asked. Please, what am I doing wrong? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this is what u wanted but here it is:
"while True" just let it loops over and over again.

```
students = [ ]
def add_student(name, student_id=133):
   student_name = input("Enter a name:")
   student_id = input("Enter number:")

   student = {"name": student_name, "student_id": student_id}
   students.append(student)
   return students


while True:
   add_more_student = input("Do you want to add students to this list? (yes/NO):")
   if add_more_student == 'yes':
           add_student(())
           print(students)
   elif add_more_student == "no":
       print(students)
       break
```

hopefully this is what u were looking for ^^
edit:
sorry it shoudnt be:

```
elif add_more_student == "no":
```

but

```
else:
```